# css div to full viewport height and no scrollbar

Tags: css

I have a top navigation with buttons and `width:100%`, put the body and html height to 100% and div height to 100% , it gives me scrollbar, how can I prevent this? when div have no paddings works fine by the way.

```html
<button class="tablink">Home</button>
<button class="tablink">News</button>
<button class="tablink">Contact</button>
<button class="tablink">About</button>
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box - sizing: border - box;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100 %;
}

.tablink {
  float: left;
  width: 25 %;
  padding: 14 px 16 px;
}

.tabcontent {
  background - color: cadetblue;
  height: 100 vh;
  padding: 100 px 20 px;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a jsfiddle or codepen link?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your

```
body,html{
height:100%;}
```

to:

```
body,html{
height:100vh;}
```

and see if that fixes it. Also you can force it by adding `overflow: hidden;` to your `body,html` as well.